# How does JavaScript evaluate operator precedence in this scenario?

Tags: javascript

I have below code and I just wanted to understand how the operator precedence working in this scenario. Just wanted to go back to old school and see how it works in JavaScript.

```
var num1 = 5,
    num2 = 10,
    result = (num1++)+num2;
    result1 = num1+++num2;
    result2 = (++num1)+num2;

console.log(result);
console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

The above is printing as

```
15 
16
18
```

respectively.

1. Shouldn't `result1` be throwing a syntax error?
2. I did not get how `result2` is `18`.

Comment: Off topic, and I know this is just a quick demo, but notice that you're creating global variables with `result1` and `result2`. I'd recommend either a single line or leading commas instead of trailing to avoid that.

Comment: As to why the `result1` isn't a syntax error, space around operators is optional and the tokenizer grabs as much as it can to create a valid token. So it first creates `num1` since the `+` isn't a valid identifier character. Then it grabs the first `+` but tries to keep going since `++` and `+=` are also valid. Since it finds another `+`, it grabs that too. Now that there's no other valid token possible, it adds the `++` as a token and keeps going, where it finds a `+`. Since there's no `=` or `+` after it, the single `+` becomes a token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
result1 = num1+++num2;
```

is the same as

```
result1 = (num1++) + num2;
```

So essentially, what is happening is:

```
var num1 = 5,
    num2 = 10,
    result = (num1++) + num2; //5 + 10, then 5->6
    result1 = (num1++) + num2; //6 + 10, then 6->7
    result2 = (++num1) + num2; // 7->8, then 8 + 10
```